# Селектор Jquery для элемента input

Tags: jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста какой универсальный селектор можно составить для элементов input с name="hide_field_*", где ***** - любое число.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это подойдёт(?):

```
 $('input[name^="hide_field_"]')
```

или непременно нужно проверить наличие числа?

Comment: Непременно наличие числа нужно проверить

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, тогда понадобится ещё .filter присовокупить

Comment: Щас изучу filter

Comment: Как-то так:

     $('input[name^="hide_field_"]').filter("['hide_fields_'$name]")

Comment: .filter(function( return /_\d+$/.test($(this).attr('name')) ))

Comment: с [этой штукой](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/) можно использовать regexp'ы в селекторах

Comment: А если нужно селектор применить к событию click?

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, а вы будете кликать на hide_fields?
дайте им общий класс и не мучайтесь больше.